# How do I stop axios response propagation inside interceptor

Tags: axios, interceptor

I have an axios interceptor where I catch a 401 error and redirect the user to the login page. The problem is that after the window.location runs and before the actual redirect - the axios operation continues to the originating caller. I would like to stop the process / cancel the propagation inside the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround - I removed all the "catch" methods from the application. I have only 1 global "catch" in the error interceptor. Then after I handle the error I call:

Promise.resolve(error);